# Constant width on screen using Unity's Line Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use Unity's line renderer to draw the trajectory of an object, however, I need this trajectory to have a constant width from the camera perspective. I've come across similar questions on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately, none of the provided solutions seem to address my specific needs. Here are the suggested solutions I've found:

1. **Convert positions to viewport space, then back to world space, and render lines on the near plane:**
   This method shows promise, but it has a drawback. It sacrifices object occlusion, meaning that if there's an object in front of the line, the line will be rendered on top of it. This occurs because the projection is to the near plane.
2. **Adjust line width based on zoom:**
   While this might work for some, it's not applicable in my case. I don't perform zooming; instead, I only pan the camera. Moreover, adjusting line width based on object distance isn't feasible since the line represents the trajectory of the object, extending significantly far from the object itself.

I've encountered suggestions about using shaders, but delving into shader programming seems daunting. I lack a starting point and would appreciate guidance on how to approach this using shaders.